# Parsing Exception when Connecting to File Location Using Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, opencmis

Ideally I would like to download a file from a source. However I continue to get a Parsing Exception each time. Based on what I'm seeing I may not be connecting  to this resource the correct way but I can't be 100% sure ...documentation on this doesn't really point me in any direction. Does the "webdav" part in this URL have anything to do with this?
I have the following code:

```
 public static void readData(String userpath) {
       ...
        //downloadCert("sapcert3.cer");
        Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // user credentials
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);

    // connection settings
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "https://.../alfresco/webdav/sites/imcflash/documentLibrary");
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());


    // set the alfresco object factory
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS, "org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl");

    // create session
        SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
        List<Repository> repos = factory.getRepositories(parameter); //throws Parsing Exception here
        Session session = factory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0).createSession(); //basically identical to the line above, also throws Parsing Exception

        CmisObject doc = session.getObject("Flash.txt");
        System.out.println("Data: " + doc.getId());

     //download file code here?
    }
```

Comment: You sure `https://.../` is valid? Or is this just elided? Please make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong URL. This page lists all CMIS endpoints for Alfresco: https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#CMIS_Service_URL

If you can, use the browser binding. It's faster and lighter and you don't need the Alfresco object factory.

Comment: That would be great but I've only been provided one URL for the document - and I may have no way of finding a URL in the format it requires for browser binding.

Comment: If you can extract the Alfresco path from the URL, you can call getObjectByPath() to get the object.

Comment: What would the alfresco path be? Almost everything in the API reference refers to http://<host>:<port>/.../... but I don't see anything like that with what I'm given.